# Distribution of lattice points visible from the origin

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, geometry-of-numbers

I am reading Apostol's book on Introduction to Analytic Number Theory. In section 3.8, he discusses the distribution of lattice points visible from the origin. While finding the density of such points he considers squares. My question is: Would the answer be any different if we consider shapes other squares for instance circles or ellipses. I tried to find the answer for circles by inscribing and circumscribing squares but ended up with inequalities which hint that the answer might be the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've almost finished writing a long answer to this question. Belatedly, I did a Google search to see what else might have been written along similar lines. This  MathOverflow answer came up: [Reference request: probability that d numbers are coprime](https://mathoverflow.net/a/371932). It appears to answer not only your question but also a $d$-dimensional generalisation of it. It's terse, and I haven't tried to plough through it properly yet. My answer is simpler, but as I said, it's long! You might be better employed working through the MO answer than waiting while I toil over my masterpiece.

Comment: Because the question needs an answer, and a mere link to a MathOverflow answer is insufficient, I've compiled a CW answer - it can be expanded, if necessary. My own draft answer doesn't seem to have much to offer when compared with Hardy and Wright's Theorem 459, which is the basis of the MO answer, so I won't post it, unless it can be improved in some way. It is based on Example 4.1 in L. Kuipers and H. Niederreiter, *Uniform Distribution of Sequences*, on the uniform distribution of the sequence of rational numbers in $(0,1]$ in ascending order of denominators when expressed in lowest terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From G. H. Hardy and E. M. Wright, *An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* (fourth edition 1960), pages 26, 29, 235, 237, 407, 409f. (lightly edited):

> We call [$\ldots$] the system of points $(x, y)$ with integral
> coordinates the *fundamental point-lattice* $\Lambda.$
> [$\ldots$]
> We call a point $P$ of $\Lambda$ *visible* (i.e. visible from
> the origin) if there is no point of $\Lambda$ on $OP$ between $O$
> and $P.$ In order that $(x, y)$ should be visible, it is necessary
> and sufficient that $x/y$ should be in its lowest terms, or
> $(x, y) = 1.$
>
> [$\ldots$]
>
> **Theorem 263.**
> $$
> \sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d) = 1 \quad (n = 1), \qquad
> \sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d) = 0 \quad (n > 1).
> $$
>
> [$\ldots$]
>
> **Theorem 270.**
> $$
> g(x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty f(mx) \iff
> f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)g(nx).
> $$
> The reader should have no difficulty in constructing a proof with
> the help of Theorem 263; but some care is required about
> convergence.  A sufficient condition is that
> $$
> \sum_{m,n}\left\lvert f(mnx)\right\rvert =
> \sum_kd(k)\left\lvert f(kx)\right\rvert
> $$
> should be convergent.  Here $d(k)$ is the number of divisors of $k.$
> $\ \square$
>
> [$\ldots$]
>
> For every $\rho > 0,$ we denote by $\Lambda(\rho)$ the lattice of
> points $(\rho x, \rho y),$ where $x, y$ take all integral values,
> and write $g(\rho)$ for the number of points of $\Lambda(\rho)$
> (apart from the origin $O$) which belong to the [given] bounded
> region $P.$ We call
> $$
> V = \lim_{\rho\to0}\rho^2g(\rho)
> $$
> *the area* of $P,$ if the limit exists.  This definition
> embodies the only property of area which we require in what follows.
> It is clearly equivalent to any natural definition of area for
> elementary regions such as polygons, ellipses, etc.
>
> [$\ldots$]
>
> For our next result we require the idea of *visible* points of
> a lattice introduced in Ch. III. A point $T$ of $\Lambda(\rho)$ is
> *visible* (i.e. visible from the origin) if $T$ is not $O$ and
> if there is no point of $\Lambda(\rho)$ on $OT$ between $O$ and $T.$
> We write $f(\rho)$ for the number of visible points of
> $\Lambda(\rho)$ belonging to $P$ and prove the following lemma.
>
> **Theorem 459.**
> $$
> \rho^2f(\rho) \to \frac{V}{\zeta(2)} \text{ as } \rho \to 0.
> $$
>
> [$\ldots$]

The proof uses Theorem 270.  It is omitted, partly because it takes
about a page, partly because I'm worried about possibly infringing
copyright, and partly because a generalisation to $\mathbb{R}^d$ for
every integer $d \geqslant 2$ has been posted as the accepted answer to the MathOverflow question
[Reference request: probability that d numbers are coprime](https://mathoverflow.net/q/357753).